# How do i make a footer?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a footer that is always at the very bottom of the webpage. I want it to contain this inside the footer:

```
    <section>
        <h3><b>AnDeb-Autos</b></h3>
        <p>07956010151<br>
        info@andebautos.com<br><br>
        <b>Post only address because we are mobile van based</b><br><br>
        Alison Business Centre,<br>
        40 Alison Crescent<br>
        Sheffield<br>
        S2 1AS</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Connect with us!<h3>
        <ul class="social">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="FACEBOOK" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="EBAY" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="GOOGLEPLUS" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

I would like it to be 100% wide and as high as it needs to be to fit everything in. I would also like it to haave a background colour of black that has an opacity so it isn't as solid.

Answer (score 1):

in your CSS stylesheet add these

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
    padding: 25px;
}

section {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```